# Relinking CSV files to a .qgz project shared with me

Tags: qgis, csv

A friend sent me a .qgz file for a project we're working on. When I opened it, it threw up the 'handle bad layers' dialogue.

I updated the filepaths to the CSVs, and they show in the legend with a feature count, however there are no points on the map.

The data column headings are visible, but not the data itself. Any idea what's up? Here's what they look like in the legend:

[image]

Comment: Heads up I'm using version 3.4.14 — Madeira